Wireguard AllowedIPs как корректно настроить?
У Wireguard есть параметр AllowedIPs. Который позволяет туннелировать запросы только к указанным ip, а другие без vpn.
Я указал диапазоны ip instagram, youtube и других сервисов:

AllowedIPs = 188.114.0.0/16, 172.64.0.0/16, 104.18.0.0/16, 64.233.0.0/16, 8.8.4.0/24, 8.8.8.0/24, 8.34.0.0/16, 8.35.0.0/16, 23.236.0.0/16, 23.251.0.0/16, 34.0.0.0/10, 35.184.0.0/13, 35.192.0.0/14, 35.196.0.0/15, 35.198.0.0/16, 35.199.0.0/17, 35.200.0.0/13, 35.208.0.0/12, 64.18.0.0/16, 66.102.0.0/16, 66.249.0.0/16, 70.32.0.0/16, 72.14.0.0/16, 74.114.0.0/16, 74.125.0.0/16, 104.132.0.0/16, 104.133.0.0/16, 104.134.0.0/15, 104.156.0.0/16, 104.237.0.0/16, 108.59.0.0/16, 108.170.0.0/16, 108.177.0.0/15, 130.211.0.0/16, 136.112.0.0/12, 146.148.0.0/16, 162.216.0.0/16, 162.222.0.0/16, 172.110.0.0/16, 172.217.0.0/16, 172.253.0.0/16, 173.194.0.0/16, 173.255.0.0/16, 192.158.0.0/16, 192.178.0.0/15, 193.186.0.0/16, 199.36.0.0/16, 199.192.0.0/16, 199.223.0.0/16, 207.223.0.0/16, 208.65.0.0/16, 208.68.0.0/16, 208.81.0.0/16, 208.117.0.0/16, 209.85.0.0/16, 216.58.0.0/16, 216.239.0.0/16, 34.64.0.0/10, 34.128.0.0/10, 142.251.0.0/16, 212.188.0.0/16, 142.250.0.0/16, 185.38.0.0/16, 108.177.0.0/16, 45.64.0.0/16, 69.63.0.0/16, 69.171.0.0/16, 74.119.0.0/16, 103.4.0.0/16, 129.134.0.0/16, 157.240.0.0/16, 173.252.0.0/16, 185.60.0.0/16, 204.15.0.0/16, 66.220.0.0/16, 179.60.0.0/16, 57.144.0.0/16, 68.66.0.0/16, 83.174.0.0/16, 84.15.0.0/16, 87.245.0.0/16, 92.46.0.0/16, 124.108.0.0/16, 129.134.0.0/16, 163.70.0.0/16, 185.89.0.0/16, 216.40.0.0/16, 217.168.0.0/16, 31.13.0.0/16, 69.63.0.0/16, 103.4.96.0/30, 162.159.0.0/16, 81.29.0.0/16, 104.31.0.0/16, 176.97.0.0/16, 194.110.0.0/16, 172.67.0.0/16, 46.19.0.0/16, 5.45.0.0/16, 193.46.0.0/16, 188.114.0.0/16, 195.123.0.0/16, 190.115.0.0/16, 185.53.0.0/16, 72.52.0.0/16, 94.140.0.0/16, 104.21.0.0/16, 104.244.0.0/16, 151.101.0.0/18, 209.237.0.0/16, 34.243.0.0/16, 69.195.0.0/17, 185.199.0.0/16, 192.133.0.0/16, 199.59.0.0/16, 199.96.0.0/13, 188.114.88.0/21, 188.114.0.0/16, 188.114.98.224/32, 18.66.147.35/32, 104.18.7.192/32, 188.114.99.238/32, 104.18.27.221/32, 104.18.30.2/32, 104.18.41.241/32, 188.114.98.238/32, 188.114.99.235/32, 188.114.98.235/32, 104.18.26.221/32, 104.18.33.45/32, 18.66.147.69/32, 104.18.7.87/32, 104.18.17.170/32, 104.18.7.201/32, 184.105.99.79/32, 18.66.147.112/32, 172.64.146.15/32, 142.250.186.115/32, 104.18.6.192/32, 104.18.6.87/32, 23.35.228.138/32, 18.66.147.17/32, 104.18.8.73/32, 13.107.246.60/32, 20.118.40.5/32, 104.18.9.73/32, 104.18.16.170/32, 172.64.154.211/32, 104.18.31.2/32, 104.18.6.201/32

На Windows клиенте всё отлично работает. А на Android при попытке подключения ошибка "Ошибка при запуске туннеля: Bad address". Понятно, что под разные ОС разная реализация клиента и на разных языках программирования. Какой ip в неправильном формате, как узнать? Или ему требуется добавить туда какой то ip, например локальный ip телефона, или ip vpn сервера, или локальный ip vpn сервера?
Надеюсь, что решение найдется и это поможет кому то. В интернете не нашел толкового ответа. Спасибо.

Почму вы решили, что проблема в AllowedIPs? Я вставил весь этот список в свой wireguard на андроиде, и всё прекрасно запустилось без ошибок

Хмм... У меня с этим списком не работает на андроиде, а без списка работает. Версия у вас тоже 1.0.20231018?

А, это я дурак вставил настройку не в том месте, сейчас вставил в том и тоже получил Bad address

Ну а так-то 108.177.0.0/15 неправильный, должно быть или 108.176.0.0/15 или 108.177.0.0/16 смотря что вы имели в виду (возможно, Windows клиент добрый и игнорирует ошибки, если не заругался)

@andreymal спасибо! Замена 108.177.0.0/15 на 108.177.0.0/16 решило проблему )
